# Why do the coefficients of this series grow like a polynomial?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, inequality, analytic-number-theory

**Set-up**

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a multiplicative arithmetic function (meaning that $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime). Suppose that for every $\epsilon >0,$ that $$f(n) \ll_\epsilon n^\epsilon,$$ here I am using Vinogradov’s notation, this means that $|f(n)| \leq C_\epsilon n^\epsilon$ for some constant $C_\epsilon$ which depends on $\epsilon.$.

Suppose further that for each prime $p, f(p)=g $ for some $g \geq 1.$ This $g$ is thus independent of $p.$.

Consider now, for a prime p, the identity of formal power series $$1+gX+f(p^2)X^2 + \cdots = (1-X)^{-g} h_p(X).$$ It is then easy to see that $h_p(0)=1,h_p’(0)=0.$.

**Question**. 
Let now $b_p(k)$ be the coefficient of $X^k$ in $h_p(X).$ I have seen it claimed that the coefficients $b_p(k)$ are bounded by a polynomial in $k$ that is independent of $p.$
Could someone explain why this holds?

Comment: Let $f(p) = g,f(p^k) = \log p$ then $f(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n}f(p^k)  = O(n^\epsilon)$ even if $ f(p^k)$ isn't bounded by a polynomial of $k$. If you mean a polynomial of $p^k$ then it is immediate from $f(n) = O(n)$. Also (for a multiplicative function) $f(n) = O(n^\epsilon)$  iff $f(p^k) =  O((p^k)^\epsilon)$

Comment: @reuns I’d be careful with epsilons in the last statement.  If $f(p^k) = 2p^k$ then it isn’t quite true that $f(n) = O(n)$, but it’s close.

Comment: @reuns I really want a polynomial in $k,$ not in $p^k.$  Are you giving a counterexample? I am not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: @reuns Sorry to bother you, but you would not have an idea how to solve this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311789/why-does-this-interval-contain-at-least-x-5-logx-primes?noredirect=1#comment6813963_3311789 question? it seems as if it should be quite easy for you.

Answer (score -2):

Here's my naive approach.

Let
$a(x)
=1+gX+f(p^2)X^2 + \cdots
=\sum_{n-0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
so that
$(1-x)^{-g} h_p(x)
=a(x)
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
h_p(x)
&=a(x)(1-x)^g\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \sum_{j=0}^g \binom{g}{j}(-1)^{g-j}x^{g-j}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \sum_{j=0}^g \binom{g}{j}(-1)^{j}x^{j}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} a_{n-i} \binom{g}{i}(-1)^{i}\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} a_{n-i} \binom{g}{i}(-1)^{i}|
&\le \sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} |a_{n-i} \binom{g}{i}|\\
&\le \sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} g^if(p^{n-i})\\
&\le g^g\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} f(p^{n-i})\\
&\le g^g\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n, g)} C_{\epsilon}(n-i)^{\epsilon}\\
&\le g^{g+1}C_{\epsilon}n^{\epsilon}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Why is $f(p^{n-i}) \leq C_\epsilon (n-i)^\epsilon?$ We only have that $f(n) \leq C_\epsilon n^\epsilon, $ so rather $f(p^{n-i}) \leq C_\epsilon (p^{n-i})^\epsilon.$ Am I missing something?

Comment: Naw. Just my usual carelessness. I'll leave it up in case someone can make it right.