# Why does this interval contain at least $x/(5\log(x))$ primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $$A_x = (x/2,x] \cup (x/4,x/3] \cup (x/6,x/5] \cup \cdots.$$ I can prove that $$\sum_{n \in A_x} \Lambda(n) = \log(2)x+O(\log(x)),$$ and that further, the error term cannot be improved.

Given this, an exercise in the book "A course in Analytic Number Theory" by Marius Overholt asks to deduce from this that the interval $(x/2,x]$ contains at least $x/(5\log(x))$ primes for all $x$ sufficiently large. How do I do this?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for "proof of Bertrand's postulate" may provide some insight...

Comment: @abiessu Where exactly?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: I'm thinking of the section detailing why $\binom {2n}n$ doesn't have any prime factors arising from the interval $[\frac 23n,n]$.

Comment: @abiessu I do not see how this helps here. If you have an answer, I would appreciate it if you wrote it down.

Comment: The obvious line of attack is to, of course, show that if the interval contains less than $x/(5\log(x))$ primes, we get a better error term, but I can not see how this happens.

Comment: $2={2\over 3}\cdot 3$ similar with other bounds.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I do not understand, would you mind saying how it is relevant? If you know an answer, please try to write it down or at least write a bit longer to make the argument clearer.

Comment: Most of the gaps are where central binomial coeffients don't have prime factors.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Can you use this to answer the question? If so, I would please ask you to write up an answer, since I have tried with that approach but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: I'm not that advanced. I'm closer to a numerologist\crank.